# Convergence of infinite product to exponential

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function, infinite-product

Let $x_n\to x$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers with limit $x\in\mathbb R$.

Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{x_k}{n}\right)=e^x.$$

Is this true? 
*(Note: The formula has $n$ in the denominator and not the index $k$.)*

Here is an attempt at a proof:

$$\begin{aligned}
\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{x_k}{n}\right)&=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac xn+\frac{x_k-x}{n}\right)\\
&=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n+\left(1+\frac xn\right) \prod_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{x_k-x}{n}\right) +\text{stuff}\\
\end{aligned}$$
where the "stuff" will include many terms that look like a power of $\left(1+\frac xn\right)$ times some product of factors like $\left(\frac{x_k-x}{n}\right)$ and thus every other term will be decaying to zero (as $n\to\infty$) no matter how slow $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Thus taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ gives the desired result.

Now the problem is that we have infinite products still in there like $\prod_{\text{some } k} \left(\frac{x_k-x}{n}\right)$, but each factor in the infinite product has form $\frac{x_k-x}{n}$ and hence goes to zero. But I am very uncertain about this reasoning. I worry the infinite products might be very badly behaved.

I'm just wondering what technical issues I might be overlooking, and if I am making any mistakes in my argument, or if the argument is sort of correct but insufficient according to common practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not convinced. The "stuff" consists of various small terms that all will become very small, but at the same time, there will be more and more of these terms as $n \to \infty$. As with a Riemann sum, we expect to sum a lot of small quantities and take the limit, but this doesn't imply the Riemann integral is always $0$.

Here's how I would approach it:

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $N \in \Bbb{N}$ be such that
$$n \ge N \implies |x_n - x| < \varepsilon$$
and $x_n > -N$ (which we can do, as convergent sequences are bounded). Then, for $n > N$,
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) \cdot \prod_{k=N}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right),$$
where
$$\left(1 + \frac{x - \varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n-N+1} \le \prod_{k=N}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) \le \left(1 + \frac{x + \varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n-N+1}.$$
Since $x_n > -N$ and $n > N$, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) > 0,$$
so
$$\left(1 + \frac{x - \varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n-N+1} \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left(1 + \frac{x_n}{n}\right) \le \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) \le \left(1 + \frac{x + \varepsilon}{n}\right)^{n-N+1} \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \left(1 + \frac{x_n}{n}\right).$$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$,
$$e^{x - \varepsilon} \le \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{x_k}{n}\right) \le e^{x + \varepsilon},$$
for all $\varepsilon > 0$. So, if you accept that the product converges, the limit must be $e^x$, by the continuity of $e^x$.

Comment: The traditional bad stuff good stuff proof, where the bad stuff is at the beginning and limited, and all the good stuff is at the end and overrides the bad stuff.

Comment: Why would $x_k<-k$ be an issue? Some bound exists $-M\leq x_k\leq M$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$, hence all of the factors in the product are all positive and close to one for $n$ large enough: $0<1-\frac Mn \leq 1+\frac{x_k}n \leq 1+\frac Mn\approx 1$ for all $k$ as long as $n$ is large enough. So the product will never be negative, nor could it ever be zero.

Comment: Besides that, your argument works I think. The key I was missing was to turn $|x_k-x|<\epsilon$ into $x-\epsilon<x_k<x+\epsilon$ and use that to get the bounds on the $\prod_{k=N}^n(1+\frac{x_k}n)$.

Comment: @jdods Sorry, I left a paragraph in from a previous draft. It's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure I understood correctly! This is very helpful!

Comment: I think a reader is likely to think the formula is $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{x_k}{k})$ instead of  $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{x_k}{n})$, with the $k$ denominator there are definitely potential problems to consider. I'll add a note to my question just to make sure a passive reader knows this.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick. There is no need to "accept that the product converges" rather we can use that $\liminf, \limsup$ of the product lies between $e^{x-\epsilon}, e^{x+\epsilon} $ and therefore the product converges to $e^x $. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @martycohen: I like the phrase "bad stuff good stuff proof". Sounds very similar to "bad cop good cop".